# can it be possible to make classes that can be referenced by back-end and front-end?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working on Google Apps Script, and I don't use V8 runtime so I have to deal with this in ES5.

I have a class that I want to use on both back-end and front-end. Can it be possible?

At the moment, I don't know how to do it, but I have to make duplicated same class for both ends.

For example, I would have gs file and html file that have the same code:

-TestClass_backend.gs

```
var Test = function(){
  this._a;
}
```

-TestClass_frontEnd.html

```
<script>
var Test = function(){
  this._a;
}
</script>
```

I want to put together the same codes to avoid duplicate. Thanks in advance.

---

**Added:** I also tried this:

index.html in frontend:

```
<body>
    <script>
        var Test = <?!= Test ?> 

        //test for the constructor
        console.log("Test="+Test);//Test=function(a) {  this._a = a; }

        var test = new Test("hello");

        //test for the property
        console.log("test.a="+test.a);//test.a=undefined

        //test for the method
        var a = test.getA();//Uncaught TypeError: test.getA is not a function
        console.log("a="+a);
    </script>
</body>
```

Test.gs in backend:

```
var Test = function(a) {
  this._a = a;
}

Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, "a", {
  get: function() {
    return this._a;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    this._a = value;
  },
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true
});

Test.prototype.getA = function(){
  return this._a;
}
```

so, it looks the constructor could be passed to the front-end, but not others..

---

**Added 2:** I also tried this:

I put test declaration and defineProperty in a separate .html file with script tags, then included it in front end. In the backend, did the same, except strip out  with regex and then eval the resulting plain js. But it didn't work either..

index.html in front-end:

```
<body>
    <?!= include('Test.html'); ?>
    <?!= include('Test_property.html'); ?>
    <script>
      window.onload = function(){
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(getTest_ok)
          .withFailureHandler(getTest_ng)
          .getTest();
      }

      function getTest_ok(testJSON){
        //test for constructor
        var test = JSON.parse(testJSON);
        console.log("test.name="+test.name);//test.name=undefined
        console.log("test.constructor.name="+test.constructor.name);//test.constructor.name=Object

        //test for property
        console.log("test.a="+test.a);//test.a=undefined

        //test for method
        var a = test.getA();//Uncaught TypeError: test.getA is not a function
        console.log("a="+a);
      }
      function getTest_ng(){
        console.log("getTest_ng");
      }

    </script>
  </body>
```

Test.gs in backend:

```
function include(filename) {
  var ua = HtmlService.getUserAgent();
  var inclueFile = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
  return inclueFile;
}

var file_str_Test = include("Test.html");
file_str_Test = removeScriptTag(file_str_Test);
eval(file_str_Test); 

var file_str_Test_property = include("Test_property.html");
file_str_Test_property = removeScriptTag(file_str_Test_property);
eval(file_str_Test_property); 

function removeScriptTag(file_str_Test){
  var file_str_Test = file_str_Test.replace(/^<script>/i, "");
  file_str_Test = file_str_Test.replace(/<\/script>/i, "");

  return file_str_Test;
}

function getTest(){
  var test = new Test("from-backend");
  Logger.log("test.a="+test.a);//test.a=from-backend

  return JSON.stringify(test);
}
```

Test.html

```
<script>
var Test = function(a) {
  this._a = a;
}
</script>
```

Test_property.html

```
<script>
Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, "a", {
  get: function() {
    return this._a;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    this._a = value;
  },
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true
});

Test.prototype.getA = function(){
  return this._a;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is both backend/front end code in the same project?

Comment: @mwilson Yes, in the same project.

Comment: @TheMaster I'm sorry, what is "g.s.run"? I want to use the same custom collection and information class to store data and do something with the data. And sometimes, I want to use custom tool function in both sides.

Comment: @TheMaster I might got it. g.s.run is google.script.run. Yes, I think we can pass the class from backend to frontend using it but we can't read the class on frontend where the class  is not defined.

Comment: How about plain templates? `var class = <?!= thisclass ?> `

Comment: @TheMaster I see. I thought good idea. Thank you. I tried it but only works for the part of the constructor. It doesn't work for property and method part.

Comment: @TheMaster Ok. I added relevant code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212860/discussion-between-herbert-and-themaster).

Comment: You didn't say you want to pass a class instance. My solution was aimed at deduplication and based on "Added1". For example, your "Added1" index.html will work now, if modified like this: `<body>
    <?!= include('Test.html'); ?>
    <?!= include('Test_property.html'); ?>
    Bla bla
    <script>
    alert(new Test("hello").a)
    </script>
    <body>`

Comment: @TheMaster Ok, I see. Yes, it works great to achieve dedupulication. Thanks. it would be perfect if there is any way to pass a class instance..

Comment: I got nothing. If you're willing to pursue, maybe ask a new question. Others might know something. If no one else knows, you may need to wait for  imports exports support in  v8

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 `import` and `export` to accomplish this.

[export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

[import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

```js
// my-class.js
export class MyClass {
  constructor(a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}


// my-front-end.js
import MyClass from '/somewhere/my-class.js';
const c = new MyClass('test');


// my-backend.js
import MyClass from '/somewhere/my-class.js';
const c = new MyClass('test');
```

If for whatever reason you can't us `import`/`export`, you can do it the "old way". Doing it this way would require you to reference your shared class (the js file) in both front/backend.

```js
// my-class.js
function MyClass(a) {
  this.a = a;
}

MyClass.prototype = {
  sayHello: function() {
    alert(this.a);
  }
};


// backend.js
const c = new MyClass('test');
c.sayHello();

// front-end.js
const c1 = new MyClass('test');
c1.sayHello();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to use the old way but is it possible in google apps script environment?

Comment: I haven't worked with it, but if you are saying it's all in a single project, sharing files should be very trivial.

Comment: Worst case scenario, you could upload your shared js file to some cdn and just reference the url

Comment: I see. Uploading shared js file to cdn needs me to upload it every time after modifying it, so it's not practical solution. Anyway, thanks for your advise.

Comment: and the nodejs require() accomplish too when you use any module loader in frontend build

Comment: ^incorrect. `require` is only available in nodejs. It will not work in a browser. You have to use `import` for client side.